# How to transition from Final Cut Pro 6 (or 7) to 10

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro

I was a professional video editor in the early to mid 2000's. At the time, I used FCP versions 3 through 6 and was fluid with the program. I worked in the demo commercial business making pretty complicated animations out of layered Photoshop files, managing constant client changes, keeping files organized, knew the keyboard shortcuts, etc. I also had my own art projects. Around 2009, I switched careers (to math education).

Recently, I decided to incorporate some of my video editing skills into what I do now. I picked up FCP 10.5 and was surprised by how different it is. For example, I can't even open any of the my old .fcp files. I've heard of drastic software updates but have never heard of an application's own default file type becoming unrecognizable to itself! This seems more of a symptom than the problem, as the whole file linking method is different. The whole nomenclature for what they call shots, clips, timelines, is different. So much is different! I go online looking for help and find videos of people half my age, who know half the stuff I used to know (but on 6), talking to me like I'm an idiot.

Okay, enough whining.

I want to get up to speed on using FCP 10.5. Does anyone here know of a good tutorial, or set of documentation on this? I'd settle for something on learning about the transition from FCP 7 to X, as that seems to be where most of the changes happened, even though I never used 7. I would also be interested in an effective means of reviving my FCP 6 projects in 10.5, but that's not the main content of this question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point would be [Apple](https://www.apple.com/final-cut-pro/resources/) itself.

Known for tutorials are larryjordan.com and rippletraining.com

A good book is from [Ian Anderson](http://fcpefficientediting.com/)